# Problems with request mapping

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-security, request-mapping

I have problems with request mapping in Spring web app. Here is my controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/user")
public class UserController {
    @RequestMapping("/is-logged")
    public Boolean isLogged() {
        return UserUtils.getUser() != null;
    }

    @RequestMapping("/account")
    public AccountView getAccount() {
        return UserUtils.getUser();
    }
}
```

If I try to request `http://localhost:8080/server/user/is-logged` I receive boolean value. If I try to request `http://localhost:8080/server/user/account` I receive 404 error message. But, if I change request mapping annotation from `account` to anything else, everything works correctly. I tried it twice, and always same result.

I'm using Maven build and Apache Tomcat 8.5.0

Is it some kind of hidden Spring MVC or Spring Security mapping? Here is my Spring Security config:

```
 http.csrf().disable()
                .headers().frameOptions().disable()
                .headers().xssProtection().disable()
                .headers().httpStrictTransportSecurity().disable()
               // .addFilterBefore(usernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .httpBasic().disable()
                    .formLogin()
                    .loginProcessingUrl("/server/login")
                    .successHandler(successHandler())
                    .failureHandler(failureHandler())
                .and()
                    .sessionManagement()
                    .sessionFixation().migrateSession()
                    .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.IF_REQUIRED)

                .and()
                    .logout()
                    .logoutUrl("/server/logout")
                    .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
                    .logoutSuccessHandler(successLogoutHandler())
                    .invalidateHttpSession(true);
```

Comment: Please add the log

Comment: There is no any usefull logs. If it is truly interesting for you, I can try to make example

Comment: How are you invoking the URL ? with a form ? or copying the URL in the browser ? or ajax call

Comment: As you can see, I did not specify request method in request mapping, so you can call this url by any method. I try to call it by xhr and by browser.